# Glowing Effect and Blending

Tags: c++, sdl, blending

I am using C++ and SDL and I am trying to get lines with a glowing effect as provided by the image of the game Defcon on the continental outlines. [image: Defcon]

How could I achieve this glow and blend of the color in 2D? What are some algorithms that I can implement or built in functions that some other graphical frame work has?

I attempted my own solution by rendering lines around the bright center line and reducing its hue but I believe that such method is too expensive in rendering. I need something more efficient.

Comment: Google for "bloom effect" and you should find plenty of material on this.